# Random vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the disk. Find the joint distribution of $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\theta =\arctan (Y/X)$

Tags: probability-theory, transformation

> Random vector $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the disk $D_r$ defined by
>   $$D_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq r\}.$$
>   Find the joint distribution of $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\Theta=\arctan\frac{Y}{X}$.

Need a kick starter or any hints. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The notation strongly suggests the use of polar coordinates :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common cumulative distribution of $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and $\Theta=\arctan\left(\frac YX\right)$ is by definition

$$F_{R,\Theta}(p,t)=P(R<p\cap\Theta<t)=\frac{T_{red}}{r^2\pi}=\frac{p^2\frac{t}{2\pi}}{r^2}, \,\,\, 0\le p\le r,\,\,0\le t \le 2\pi$$
where $T_{red}$ is the area of the red region depicted below.

[image]

The common density can be calculated by taking the following second order partial derivative:

$$f_{R,\Theta}(p,t)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p\partial t}F_{R,\Theta}(p,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac p{\pi r^2},& \text{ if } 0\le p\le r,\,\,0\le t \le 2\pi\\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: +1 (although I preferred the version without Edit 2...).

Comment: @Did: Thx. But why?

Comment: Because it is always best to leave to the OP something to do.

Comment: I do understand how to get pdf from cdf but the step I do not understand how do they get cdf. Could you give me a link were someone derives it? I need to understand that step too.

Comment: Got the derivation from the internet. Thanks.

Comment: I was about to give an answer. What did you find?

Comment: They used the pdf with  $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Then they used transformation. Maybe yours is simpler? Here is the link:http://narimanfarsad.blogspot.com/2012/11/uniformly-distributed-points-inside.html

Comment: @Don, Don't you see how much simpler my solution is. It is based on the definition of the uniform distribution. (Area/Total area)

Comment: Yeah, but I thought I get into details how they come up with the distribution function. I like your explanation but what I wanted more was what is going on up to distribution function.

Comment: I don't know. Compile a question where _that_ is important. Then again I will try to do something.