# Random variables expressed in polar coordinates: exercise

Tags: probability-distributions, polar-coordinates, solution-verification, independence, uniform-distribution

> Consider $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed over a circle disk with center $(0,0)$ and radius $m$. Let $(R,\Theta)$ be stochastic random variables such that ($R\in \mathbb{R}^+, \Theta\in[0,2\pi)$)$$ \begin{cases} X = R\cos(\Theta)\\ Y=R\sin(\Theta)\end{cases}.$$ Find the joint pdf of $(R,\Theta)$. Are $R$ and $\Theta$ independent? Calculate $Var(X)$.

**My attempt:**

Solving for $(R,\Theta)$ gives $\begin{cases} R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \\ \Theta=\operatorname{arctan}(Y/X)\end{cases}$. Thus $$ f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=f_{X,Y}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac y x\right)\right)\cdot \left| \det\begin{pmatrix} \frac{x}{\sqrt{ x^2+y^2}} & \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} & \frac x {x^2+y^2}\end{pmatrix}\right|.$$

- The last factor is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac 1r $.
- The first one is equal to $\frac 1{\pi m^2}$ if $x^2+y^2+\operatorname{arctan}^2(y/x)\le m^2 \iff r^2+\theta^2\le m.$

This results in $$ f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi r m^2}I(r^2+\theta^2\le m).$$

To check independence, we compute the marginal distributions:

$$ f_R(r)=\frac{2\sqrt{m-r^2}}{\pi r m^2}I(r^2\le m).$$ $$ f_{\Theta}(\theta)=\frac 1{\pi m^2}[\ln\sqrt{m-\theta^2}-\ln(-\sqrt{m-\theta^2})]I(\theta^2\le m).$$

Thus $R$ and $\Theta$ are dependent.

For the calculation of $Var(X)$, I would just calculate $E[X^2]$ and $E[X]$. The problem is that we need information about $X$ only here. Do I use $X=R\cos(\Theta)$ and the joint pdf of $(R,\Theta)$ to find the expectation values?

Also, can we deduce whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I know that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{\pi m^2}I(x^2+y^2\le m)$. The marginal distributions will have square roots that won't disappear in the product and therefore $f_Xf_Y\ne f_{X,Y}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Statistical independence and causal independence are different things, but logically, the radius, $R$, and the angle from the positive $x$-axis, $\Theta$, should be causally independent, since the points are chosen uniformly from the interior of a circle centered at at the origin. If it is the case that they are not statistically independent (as your calculation suggests), then this would be an interesting example of two things that are causally independent but not statistically independent.

Comment: $\mathbb P(R<r, \Theta<\theta)$ is the probability that randomly chosen point in the circle disc appears in circular sector of the circle with radius $r$, where central angle of the sector is $\theta$. This probability equals to $\dfrac{r^2}{m^2}\cdot \dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$. So joint pdf is $f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=\dfrac{2r}{m^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @NCh and so they are independent with $f_{R}(r)=\dfrac{2r}{m^2}$ when $r \in [0,m]$and $f_{\Theta}(\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ when $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$

Comment: @Henry Of course yes.

Comment: @NCh this is a very clever intuitive solution. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question(s !). I am wondering why my approach gives an incorrect pdf...

Comment: Here is one of several posts of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533056/random-vector-x-y-is-uniformly-distributed-on-the-disk-find-the-joint-distr

Comment: @Zachary I understand that the question was asked about what is wrong in your calculations. But it’s hard for me to find problems in your solution, so I hope someone kindly understands it and then writes the answer.

Comment: What should I do with $Var(X)$? Suppose we want to find $E[X]$ first. I thought: $E[X]=E[R\cos(\Theta)]=\int\int r\cos(\theta)f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)dr d\theta$ (over the appropriate intervals). Is this OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Density of $(X,Y)$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{\pi m^2}\mathbf1_{x^2+y^2< m^2}$$

Applying the polar change of variables $(x,y)\to (r,\theta)$, the jacobian of transformation is $r$.

Clearly, $$x^2+y^2< m^2\implies r^2< m^2\implies 0<r<m$$

Note that $-m<x,y<m$, so $\tan\theta=y/x$ can take any real value. This means $$0<\theta<2\pi$$

Hence the density of $(R,\Theta)$ is $$f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{r}{\pi m^2}\mathbf1_{0<r<m,0<\theta<2\pi}$$

That is, $$f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=\frac{2r}{m^2}\mathbf1_{0<r<m}\frac1{2\pi}\mathbf1_{0<\theta<2\pi}$$

As the joint density factors into two marginal densities, **$R$ and $\Theta$ are independent**.

And as you can see this standard approach is not quite as intuitive here as working with the distribution function of $(R,\Theta)$.

Now since $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent, so are $R$ and $\cos\Theta$. Therefore expectation of $X$ is $$\operatorname E[R\cos\Theta]=\operatorname E[R] \operatorname E[\cos\Theta]$$

A quick calculation would give $\operatorname E[\cos\Theta]=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta=0$, which is also clear from the fact that distribution of $X$ is symmetric about $0$. Similarly find $\operatorname E[X^2]=\operatorname E[R^2]\operatorname E[\cos^2\Theta]$ and hence the variance of $X$.